# Difference between the way we access properties in javascript

Tags: javascript

Actually i have searched a lot for this on google. This is very basic question.

This is my script

```
var test = new Object();
test["test"] = 1;

$("#dot").html(test.test);
$("#bracket").html(test["test"]);
```

This is my html

```
<div id="dot"></div>
<div id="bracket"></div>
```

For reference, here is http://jsfiddle.net/PWA5G/1/ URL.

My question is what is exact difference between `test.test` and `test["test"]` as my output is same.

This question or thread might have repeated but i didn't find any related results.

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]` operator allows you to use attribute names which cannot be used with `.` operator. For example

```
var test = {};
test["invalid-attr"] = 1;
console.log(test["invalid-attr"]);
# 1
console.log(test.invalid-attr);
# ReferenceError: attr is not defined
```

When we use `[]` operator with a string in it, it just gets the value corresponding to that by hashing the attribute name we pass. But, if the attribute name is not syntactically valid, then the `.` operator will fail.

Comment: also allows you to access your properties with strings.

Answer (score 0):

there is some difference, it allows you to use reserved names...but mainly `abc['test']` helps when property name is variable.

Like this:

```
var a ={};
a.q=2;
a.w=3;
a.e=4;

//on user input

var input = event.key
console.log(a[input]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate in box86rowh with an example. Also note that the target can be either a method or a property. Granted it's a bit contrived, but it demonstrates the flexibility of bracket notation.

```
<p><input type="checkbox" id="needsBillingAddress"><label for="needsBillingAddress">Different Billing Address</label></p>

<div id="billingAddress">
   <p>Billing Address goes here</p>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        (showHideBillingAddress = function() {
            $('#billingAddress')[ $('#needsBillingAddress').is(':checked') ? 'show':'hide' ]();
        })();
        $('#needsBillingAddress').click( showHideBillingAddress );
    });
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/kQ3Hr/